# Request for proper word - "bur?"

Tags: tools, hardware

Sometimes certain things call for a washer to be put on a metal shaft, and then in order for the washer to not come back out, you would hammer the top of the shaft so that it deforms. I've heard someone call the process creating a "bur". But I don't think that's the right spelling. What's right word for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "burr" is a sharp raised edge on a piece of metal. (My dictionary says "bur" is an alternate spelling but I don't think I've ever seen that.)

Answer (score 7):

That's called [peening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peening) (Wiki).

[TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/peening) – *peen*, *v.t.* :  2. to enlarge, straighten, or smooth with a peen.

> I would like to know how to go about **[peening] over the end** of the stick tang onto the material at the very end of the handle. –[britishblades.com](http://www.britishblades.com/forums/showthread.php?15859-Peening-the-end-of-a-stick-blade)

(quote edited for misspelling)

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing is a rivet.